# If A is n element vector then how can we get a (nxn) matrix out of it with each row containing elements of A vector?

Tags: matlab, matrix

Let's say I have a vector A= [1 2 3 4 5 6]. Then I want a matrix of size 6x6 such that

B= [1 2 3 4 5 6; 1 2 3 4 5 6; 1 2 3 4 5 6; 1 2 3 4 5 6;1 2 3 4 5 6;1 2 3 4 5 6]. How to do this in MATLAB without any loop?

Answer (score 1):

```matlab
B = ones(length(A))*(diag(A));
```

This will work for any n x 1 vector A.

Comment: I would argue that `repmat()` is clearer, but this is pretty clever.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `repmat()`. I'll take a look. Regards, appreciate the feedback.